# airflow catching every error in my dag to a DB

Tags: logging, airflow, try-catch

i am looking for a way to catch every error in my dag - from any operator to my DB.
currectly - we have implemented try-catch blocks with logging function to our SF db, but when thre is a syntax error for example in the sql we are running in the dag - exception is not raised within the snowflakeoperator.
I am adding the code of my dag here, it dynamically creates and assign tasks.
Thanks for your help guys
Asaf

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

import pendulum
import logging

@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False
)
def Asaf_MNG_DAG_master_general():
    # Create Unique Run ID
    execution_timestamp = pendulum.now().format("YYYYMMDD_HHmmss")
    run_identifier = f"{execution_timestamp}"

    def log_error_to_snowflake(error_message):
        try:
            # Create a SnowflakeHook to connect to your Snowflake database.
            snowflake_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='SF_CONN')
           
            # Prepare the SQL query to insert error information into your Snowflake DB.
            sql_query = f"INSERT INTO SANDBOX.PUBLIC.SP_LOG (error_message) VALUES ('{error_message}')"
           
            # Execute the SQL query.
            snowflake_hook.run(sql_query)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle any exceptions that occur during the error logging process.
            # You might want to add additional logging here to track issues with the error logging itself.
            print(f"Error logging to Snowflake failed: {e}")

    # Define variables for the load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg 
    area_variable = "AAA"
    module_variable = "BBB"
    layer_variable = "CCC"
    action_variable = "DDD"
    
    @task
    def get_list_of_results(area, module, layer, action):
        try:
        # Wrap database connections into a task
            hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT')
            sql_query = f"SELECT QUERY, ACTIVE_FLAG FROM SANDBOX.PUBLIC.MNG_PARALLEL_AIRFLOW WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG=TRUE AND LAYER = '{layer}' AND AREA = '{area}' AND MODULE = '{module}' AND ACTION = '{action}';"
            results = hook.get_records(sql_query)
            return results
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions
            logging.getLogger("airflow.task").error(f"Task 'get_list_of_results' failed with error: {e}")
            log_error_to_snowflake(str(e))
            raise

    @task
    def create_sp_list(result):
        query = result[0]
        active_flag = result[1]
        sql = f"{query[:-2]}, '{run_identifier}');"
        return sql

    with TaskGroup("load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg") as load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg:
        try:
            results = get_list_of_results(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable)
            sql_queries = create_sp_list.expand(result=results)
            SnowflakeOperator(
                task_id="load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg",
                snowflake_conn_id="SF_CONN",
                autocommit=True,
                sql=sql_queries
            )
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions
            logging.getLogger("airflow.task").error(f"Task 'load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg' failed with error: {e}")
            log_error_to_snowflake(str(e))
            raise
        
    # Define variables for the manual_tables_handle_duplicates group of tasks
    area_variable = "AAAA"
    module_variable = "BBBB"
    layer_variable = "CCCC"
    action_variable = "DDDD"
   
    @task
    def get_list_of_results(area, module, layer, action):
        try: 
            # Wrap database connections into a task
            hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT')
            sql_query = f"SELECT QUERY, ACTIVE_FLAG FROM SANDBOX.PUBLIC.MNG_PARALLEL_AIRFLOW WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG=TRUE AND LAYER = '{layer}' AND AREA = '{area}' AND MODULE = '{module}' AND ACTION = '{action}';"
            results = hook.get_records(sql_query)
            return results
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions
            logging.getLogger("airflow.task").error(f"Task 'manual_tables_handle_duplicates' failed with error: {e}")
            log_error_to_snowflake(str(e))
            raise
    @task
    def create_sp_list(result):
        query = result[0]
        active_flag = result[1]
        sql = f"{query[:-2]}, '{run_identifier}');"
        return sql

    with TaskGroup("manual_tables_handle_duplicates") as manual_tables_handle_duplicates:
        try:
            results = get_list_of_results(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable)
            sql_queries = create_sp_list.expand(result=results)
            SnowflakeOperator(
                task_id="manual_tables_handle_duplicates",
                snowflake_conn_id="AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT",
                autocommit=True,
                sql=sql_queries
            )
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions
            logging.getLogger("airflow.task").error(f"Task 'manual_tables_handle_duplicates' failed with error: {e}")
            log_error_to_snowflake(str(e))
            raise
    # Set up the dependency
    load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg >> manual_tables_handle_duplicates

Asaf_MNG_DAG_master_general()
```

tried try-catch block, it doesnt catch all errors, and what it does - gives partial info and not sufficient

Comment: Your `try ... catch` block is in the task group definition. This code is executed at parse time only and it doesn't handle any task errors. What you need is to write a decorator and decorate every task you want to handle with that decorator. Note that you need to handle built-in exceptions separately (for example, reschedule/error/etc.)

Comment: i see, do you have an example of such decorator on every task ?